# Error 'list object' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: ansible

I have some problems with understanding how i can get value from array

I declared variable **names** using this code

```
- name: 'Collecting values'
      set_fact:
        names:
          - { name: 'Primary', host: '{{ hostname1 }}'}
          - { name: 'Secondary', host: '{{ hostname1  }}'}
```

After it i successfully used this var in the loop

```
    - include_tasks: ./sometask1.yml
      vars:
        hostname_name: '{{ item_outer.name }}'
        hostname_host: '{{ item_outer.host}}'
      loop: '{{ names}}'
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_outer
```

But in the second task

```
    - import_tasks: ./sometask2.yml
      vars:
        hostname: '{{ names.name }}'
```

I have an error

```
fatal: [example.domain.com]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'name'"
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `names` is a list of dictionaries, all those dictionaries having a `name` attribute, but the list itself does not have a `name` attribute. What are you trying to access / achieve with that non-working task?

Comment: I'm understand, thank you.
In real life second task looks like names: '{{ names.name | join(',') }}'.
I need to create string with all names separated by ','

Comment: Then: `{{ names | map(attribute='name') | join(',') }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided in the comments:

> `names` is a list of dictionaries, all those dictionaries having a `name` attribute, but the list itself does not have a name attribute. What are you trying to access / achieve with that non-working task? – [β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5) [2023-01-30 09:03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282025/error-list-object-has-no-attribute-name/75282315#comment132841236_75282025)

> I'm understand, thank you. In real life second task looks like names: '{{ names.name | join(',') }}'. I need to create string with all names separated by ',' – [Po_temkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20634622/po-temkin) [2023-01-30 09:09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282025/error-list-object-has-no-attribute-name/75282315#comment132841339_75282025)

> Then: `{{ names | map(attribute='name') | join(',') }}` – [β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5)
> [2023-01-30 09:15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282025/error-list-object-has-no-attribute-name/75282315#comment132841444_75282025)